# Load image from django rest in React JS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

Trying to get image stored in django model in react js

Firstly I have upload image from react to django rest and saved it in a model.It saved like this "/media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg".But now I want to get this image from django to react and display in  tag but it doesn't load.

**Settings.py**

```
           MEDIA_URL='/media/'
           MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**Models.py**

```
       description=models.CharField(max_length=600,blank=True,null=True)
       main_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='project_mainimage')
       videourl=models.CharField(max_length=450,blank=True,null=True)
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^portfolio/', include('PortfolioApp.urls')),

   ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**React Js component:**

```
    <img  src={this.state.project.main_image} width="184" height="40" 
    alt="Project image"/>  // shows nothing
    <h1>{this.state.project.main_image}</h1> // shows "/media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg"
```

Comment: What do you see when you type `http://localhost/media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg` into the address bar? (using the correct port of your app)

Comment: I see the image

Comment: Ok i understand now, I appended thi http://localhost/ in src image tag now its working

Comment: HI, i have the same issue right now. Can you maybe explain how you send the image to the backend?

Answer (score -3):

"/media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg" wont works . It should be a complete URL , for example "https://localhost/media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg"

For this your server should return the complete url , otherwise you can pre-bind your server address with /media/project_mainimage/newimage.jpg.

Comment: No, URLs starting with a slash are perfectly fine. The browser will use the same protocol and server as the current page.